# Django runserver inside ipdb/ipython

Tags: django, ipython

Inside ipython you can use a magic command:

```
%run -d myapp.py
```

This will run the app inside ipython and as soon as it crashes it will fire ipdb right in place to inspect the crash. How can I force django runserver to fallback right away into ipdb/ipython after encoutering an error instead of displaying error page (of course I don't need ipdb in browser - I'm talking about console I ran manage.py in)?

PS. I know about ipdb.set_trace() - I want the ipdb to be run automatically when an error occurs - this would be a real time saver!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [django-pdb](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pdb#downloads). It's very easy. The post mortem mode only is in a [fork](https://github.com/Psycojoker/django-pdb) still

Comment: Great app! I suppose it's impossible to enter ipdb on error? The app seems to run ipdb always when enabled (either by get param or by runserver param). When running inside ipython %run checks return code to run pdb?

Comment: There is a patch for post-mortem mode: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-pdb/pull/10 - would you be so kind and edit your answer for future readers and include this link? Thanks in advance!